# Basic T-SQL trigger to populate an audit table

Tags: t-sql, database-trigger, audit-tables

Having read [this page](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/) I having built a couple of tables and a trigger. The idea is that when an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` is performed on the first table `Matt` the data operated upon will be inserted into the second, audit, table `MattAudit`.

The trigger must be failing and I don't know why; The evidence is that there is no entry made in the audit table, though the `CREATE TRIGGER` and subsequent `ALTER TRIGGER` statements complete successfully.

Main table `Matt`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matt](
    [MattID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Matt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MattID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Audit table `MattAudit`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MattAudit](
    [MattAuditID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MattID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Action] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MattAudit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MattAuditID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Trigger on Matt:

```
ALTER TRIGGER TrgMattAudit ON Matt
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MattAudit]
        ( MattID, [Text], [Action], InsertedDate )
    SELECT
        ISNULL(i.MattID, d.MattID) as MattID,
        ISNULL(i.Text, d.Text) as Text,
        CASE ISNULL(i.MattID,0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        +
        CASE ISNULL(d.MattID,0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
        as [Action],
        GETDATE() as InsertedDate
    FROM
        inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.MattID = d.MattID;

END
```

The following insert statement will insert rows into the `Matt` table but nothing appears in the `MattAudit` table.

```
INSERT INTO Matt ([Text]) VALUES ('Test4')
```

What am I missing or getting wrong in the trigger?

Comment: Using triggers for audit tables might not be the best idea. There are built in tools in SQL Server like capture data change or temporal tables that can give you a better solution.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Temporal tables also work for deleted rows?

Comment: Yes. Temporal tables (A.K.A system-versioned tables) was introduced in SQL Server 2016 - the idea is that you have one table that stores the current data, and one table that stores the history of that data - and they are automatically linked - any change made in the main table will result with the current row automatically pushed to the history table - including updates and deletes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you're working with an older version, you can use Change Data Capture (which IIRC was available since 2008) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yep, [I remembered correctly...](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: @zohar-peled This might be a dumb question, but something in the way the doc you linked to describes 'current' tables makes me think they need to be defined as temporal at point of creation. I want to store auditing data for a table which has been in use for years - is that possible using a new application of a temporal history table?

Comment: @MattW you mean you have a table containing historical data and you want to use that as the history table of a temporal set? I honestly don't know if that's possible. I know you can manually create the history table, but I don't know if it can be pre-populated. I do know that once it's referenced by another table as it's history table, it is readonly - you can't update or delete records from it, nor can you insert records directly to it.

Comment: Aside: As a rule a logging trigger should be set to fire _last_ using [`sp_settriggerorder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). There's no point in logging actions that a validation trigger might rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because of this:

```
FROM
    inserted i
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.MattID = d.MattID;
```

- When inserting you only have records in `INSERTED`.
- When you delete records you only have records in `DELETED`.
- When you update records you will have records in both `INSERTED` (new value) and `DELETED` (old value).

Joining the two will always result in 0 rows for `INSERT` or `DELETE`, because when doing an INSERT you will have 1 or more rows in `INSERTED`, but 0 rows in `DELETED`. And vice versa for the `DELETE` statement.

A suggestion I would make is to split the single trigger into a trigger for each situation (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) and have a single query in each of your new triggers.

A small caveat is that an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger will add rows in both `INSERTED` and `DELETED` table.

The value in `INSERTED` will be the value which was put in place, and the value in `DELETED` will be the old value, before the UPDATE query ran.

Comment: When you are updating records, both `inserted` and `deleted` tables will contain these records - `inserted` will contains the records after the update, and `deleted` will contain the records before the update.Also, a `union all` operator will work on select statements, but not on insert statements.

Comment: Also, an after update trigger will be fired even if the update statement updated the values in the row to the same values already existing. Suppose your `Text` column contains `Matt` in the row where the id is 1, and you run `update Matt set text = 'Matt' where id = 1` - that update statement would still fire the update trigger.

Comment: I see you've edited your answer, but for the most parts of it it's still wrong... I do absolutely agree that this shouldn't be handled in a single trigger, though.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've trimmed it down. I'll proceed to cleanup the comments, since there's no need for them. When the last comment is gone, this one will go too.

Comment: "When inserting or updating you only have records in INSERTED." should be "When inserting you only have records in INSERTED." Also, "Joining the two will always result in 0 rows" should be "Joining the two will result in 0 rows for insert or delete"...

Comment: Now it's better :-) +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are doing there is to do an inner join between inserted and deleted tables. As never should be same MattId in the 2 tables. I mean, you should do outer joins like left or right (Or load variables in 2 different selects instead of doing 1). Try that, hope you understood me!

Comment: When you are updating records, both `inserted` and `deleted` tables will contain these records - `inserted` will contains the records after the update, and `deleted` will contain the records before the update.

Comment: Thats true but he wanted to audit everytime he inserts,updates or deletes so in the inserted and deletes cases his audit will fail.